# HTML page with jQuery refuses to submit?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am a beginner in jQuery, and trying to build a simple html page. The page renders fine and validates/behaves correctly using jQuery, but when everything is valid it does not get submitted on click of 'Submit' button. My complete page code of html file is as below. Why is the form refusing to submit?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css"   rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    }); ;
</script>
<script>
    $.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function (value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
 );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /**
    * @author GeekTantra
    * @date 24 September 2009
    */
    /*
    * This functions checks where an entered date is valid or not.
    * It also works for leap year feb 29ths.
    * @year: The Year entered in a date
    * @month: The Month entered in a date
    * @day: The Day entered in a date
    */
    function isValidDate(year, month, day) {
        var date = new Date(year, (month - 1), day);
        var DateYear = date.getFullYear();
        var DateMonth = date.getMonth();
        var DateDay = date.getDate();
        if (DateYear == year && DateMonth == (month - 1) && DateDay == day)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    /*
    * This function checks if there is at-least one element checked in a group of
    * check-boxes or radio buttons.   
    * @id: The ID of the check-box or radio-button group
    */
    function isChecked(id) {
        var ReturnVal = false;
        $("#" + id).find('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                ReturnVal = true;
        });
        $("#" + id).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                ReturnVal = true;
        });
        return ReturnVal;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.addMethod(
  "totalValidationDate",
   function (value, element) {

       return isValidDate(parseInt(value.split('/')[2]),  parseInt(value.split('/')[0]), parseInt(value.split('/')[1])) || this.optional(element);
   },
  "Please enter a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy"
);
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#commentForm").validate({
            rules: {
                date1: {
                    required: true,
                    totalValidationDate: true
                },
                textBox1: {
                    regex: "^[a-zA-Z'.\\s]{1,40}$"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#date1").datepicker();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="commentForm" method="get" action="http://www.yahoo.com">
 <input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" />
 <input type="text" name="textBox1" id="textBox1" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting in your js console?

Comment: There is no error. Just that the html page does not get submitted.

Comment: Have you tried using an action page other than yahoo.com?  Better yet, why don't you link to your page.

Comment: I am developing on my local machine, and so cannot link. Sorry.

Comment: Yes I have tried using other action URL, but the same result.

Comment: What was the other url you tried?

Comment: I tried http://www.google.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news!  I was able to reproduce your problem and fix it:

In your defaults declaration block, add the following:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
}
```

So that it looks like:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid",
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

I have tested it, and it works.  I don't know why you need to do this, unfortunately, but here's the fix.

Slight update for those curious, the reason this occurs is [this line in the plugin source](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L55).  It is an in-built function to prevent the submit from occurring if debug is used.

Comment: Also, I found another fix. If I remove debug: true,
then the submit works fine. So I guess, the debug attribute causes the form to not submit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was just about to correct myself with that very fix.  I found the reason why, as well: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L55

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to run it with debug more.
working example is created here. 
http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbn/2

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    });
```

should become

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        success: "valid"
    });
```

the reason is when debug = true validator allows to you check multiple use cases with out submitting the form this feature is created just to save developers time so they don't have to got back & forth. unfortunate for you this feature consumed much time instead of save.